# scp'ing from WAN to LAN

Tags: networking, ssh, lan, wwan

I want to scp files from outside of my LAN to a computer inside it.   I have sonic internet.   While I don't have a static ip address, I'm told that the external ip address that shows up on my phone is stable, so I'm hoping that there's a way of somehow connecting to a computer attached to my home LAN (assuming I know its lan address) via that external address.

I tried to set up port forwarding on the sonic app on my phone (under Settings->Advanced->Reservations and Port Forwarding, it gives me the opportunity to "Add a reservation"  but when I enter the external IP and the host name, it complains because HOST is already associated with the LAN IP address.

Could somebody suggest how I might accomplish this goal of scp-ing from outside my LAN to a machine that's inside it?

Thanks very much for any advice

Comment: A better way is to install and use a file sharing app, e.g. `dropbox`.

Comment: This is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: You can SCP in both directions.  If you go from the LAN to the WAN device, then you don't have to do port forwarding.